# Transition end event not firing

Tags: javascript, css, events, css-transitions, transition

I am coding a Polymer web component and I want to animate an element inside of it. For such thing I did the following function:

```
_animateRipple: function(x, y, color, amplitude) {
    var ripple = this.$.ripple;

    // Transition end listener
    ripple.addEventListener(this._whichTransitionEvent, transitionEndListener);

    // Ripple ended
    var transitionEndListener = function() {
        console.log("RIPPLE ENDED");
        ripple.classList.remove("transition-on");
        ripple.removeEventListener(this._whichTransitionEvent, transitionEndListener);
    }

    // Initial styling
    ripple.style.top = y + "px";
    ripple.style.left = x + "px";
    ripple.style.height = ripple.style.width = "0";
    ripple.style.backgroundColor = color;

    // Trigger ripple
    setTimeout(function() {
        ripple.classList.add("transition-on");
        ripple.style.height = ripple.style.width = amplitude + "px";
        ripple.style.top = y - (amplitude / 2) + "px";
        ripple.style.left = x - (amplitude / 2) + "px";
    }, 20);
}
```

this._whichTransitionEvent is just a variable with the correct event name for the current platform and it works fine, that is not the problem.

Obviously the .transition-on CSS class adds the transition and it works correctly.

I expect transitionEndListener to fire when transition ends (so that "RIPPLE ENDED" shows up in the console), but it is not firing.

Any ideas? I've tried a lot of things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the listener variable was undefined when being added, so the solution is to declare it before appending the event listener.

```
_animateRipple: function(x, y, color, amplitude) {
    var ripple = this.$.ripple;

    // Ripple ended
    var transitionEndListener = function() {
        console.log("RIPPLE ENDED");
        ripple.classList.remove("transition-on");
        ripple.removeEventListener(this._whichTransitionEvent, transitionEndListener);
    }

    // Transition end listener
    ripple.addEventListener(this._whichTransitionEvent, transitionEndListener);

    // Initial styling
    ripple.style.top = y + "px";
    ripple.style.left = x + "px";
    ripple.style.height = ripple.style.width = "0";
    ripple.style.backgroundColor = color;

    // Trigger ripple
    setTimeout(function() {
        ripple.classList.add("transition-on");
        ripple.style.height = ripple.style.width = amplitude + "px";
        ripple.style.top = y - (amplitude / 2) + "px";
        ripple.style.left = x - (amplitude / 2) + "px";
    }, 20);
}
```